# Spring SpEL Wiring Collection

Tags: spring, spring-el

I was reading Spring in action these days and came across the following code. I'm wondering if the following code can actually work.

```
<property name="chosenCity" value="#{cities[T(java.lang.Math).random() * cities.size()]}"/>
```

It seems like

```
T(java.lang.Math).random() * cities.size()
```

will return a double value. How can we reference a double value index in a array? The author didn't explain this? I was wondering if Spring SpEL has any auto-converting mechanism to trim a double value to int?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SpEL will provide necessary conversions (if it can). See [section 7.3.1 in the Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-evaluation-context).